# AnyLogic - simulation model documentation

Tags: anylogic

Not referring to the build-in tool "Create Documentation...", **are there any best practices and/or examples of how to document an AnyLogic model?**
Even though I am slightly unsatisfied with the documentation of java programs, that is my current "inspiration". I try to create flowcharts which describe the model's input, processing, output, and, most important but hard to break down in terms of complexity, the agent interactions.
Curious for any experiences!
Best

Comment: For which audience do you mean? Yourself as a future model developer? End users? stakeholders? Each have very different documentation needs :-)

Comment: Great differentiation, Benjamin. In my case, the audience is in between developer and end user. It needs to be clear, which modelling decisions were made and how the model works. But each single variable is not important. My flowcharts so far show the time on x- and category (input, processing, output) on the y axis. Unfortunately, that concept gets confusing as soon as I add relations of agents and databases...